# Correct usage for friendship day greeting

Tags: grammar

Out of the following, which one is a correct friendship day greeting?

> Happy Friendship's day!
>
> Happy Friendships day!
>
> Happy Friendship day!

Also, does the capital F in Friendship make sense or should it just be small f?

I have a feeling that the third greeting is correct, but I could not find any reason as to *why* the other two are wrong. Please do give a reason why they are grammatically incorrect.

Comment: You left out 'Happy Friendships' day!' But Wikipedia says it is [World] Friendship Day. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_Day **Happy Friendship Day!**

Answer (score -1):

I don't think its a problem of being "grammatically correct" or not. Its more about what is the commonly accepted naming convention.

> Labor Day, Arbor Day, Child Health Day

Follows the formula of [noun] Day (which is what Friendship Day would fall under)

> Native Americans' Day, National Library Workers' Day, Parents' Day

Days for groups of people seem to have apostrophes.

> Martin Luther King Day, Prince Jonah Kuhio Kalanianaole Day, Harvey Milk Day

Days for individual people don't have apostrophes unless..

> Valentine's Day, St. Patrick's Day, St. David's Day

It seems like religious(christian) holidays involving a specific person utilize apostrophes.